# Web service API to XML

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl

Right I have done some more research and basically I need to connect to a web service.

Here is the WSDL for the web service:
http://aecjobs.bluefusesystems.com/api/jobAPI.cfc?wsdl

The xml code below works in soapUI, but I cant figure out how to connect my xml file to the web service. It seems pretty complicated :(

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:api="http://aecjobs.bluefusesystems.com/api/jobAPI.cfc">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <api:GetJobs soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <numBusinessUnitId xsi:type="xsd:double">0</numBusinessUnitId>
      </api:GetJobs>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I guess you need to deploy your web service to a web server, then call it from there using JavaScript/PHP or any web programming langage

Comment: The web service is already deployed and working fine. I just need to figure out how to display the results (like and xml feed) onto the website.

I have written the js script that calls in the tag names from an XML file, but not sure how I create the xml file for the web service.

Answer (score 0):

We use this library, pretty easy to follow http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/

You basically fill your xml request as needed and then send an ajax request and parse the xml response to do whatever you need afterwards.